# R Colour Brewer Palettes

Tags: r

Simple questions really. Does anyone know how to find out what the colours are in RColourBrewer palettes. For eg I'm using:

```
library(RColorBrewer) 'Spectral' palette.
```

Using the palette in charts and maps is fine, but I want to know what the colours are called within the palette. Eg is it 'light green', 'dark red' etc. Or if I can find the rgb or hex value that would work just as well.

Thanks

Comment: `brewer.pal(3, "Spectral")`?